# UITableView's allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing - don't display edit circle for some cells

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to delete some rows in my `UITableView` by setting `allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing` to `YES`.  This is all working well; the circle is showing on the left hand side.

However, for certain cells, I don't want the circle on the left hand side to come up.  How do I do that?  I've tried `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone` during editing and that didn't work.

Any hints?

Comment: Custom Edit Control for UITableViewCell .     
  https://vinsol.com/blog/2015/01/06/custom-edit-control-for-uitableviewcell/

Comment: Did you ever find a working solution as well? Cause all the solutions here are not working :(

Answer (score 3):

In order to disallow some rows from multiple selection you should use `tableView:shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:` mixed with `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone`.

Here is an example from my code:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath*)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row < 4) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // (...) configure cell

    if (indexPath.row < 4) {
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
    } else {
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, use these settings:

```
self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true
self.tableView.setEditing(true, animated: false)
```

And implement next delegate methods:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return self.shouldAllowSelectionAt(indexPath)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return self.shouldAllowSelectionAt(indexPath)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
    if self.shouldAllowSelectionAt(indexPath) {
        return indexPath
    }
    return nil
}
```

shouldAllowSelectionAt is my private method which contains logic about which row to select

Comment: Maybe your answer is missing something, but still, all rows show the selection-checkmark in front... ?!?

Comment: @Georg have you implemented logic in your shouldAllowSelectionAt? Which returns false for some case?

Comment: yes, I did... but the item that should now be selectable, still shows an empty-selection-box. The UI looks ok (intent-wise) when not allowing multiple selections during edit... but with the settings just like you save in your answer, my UI looks wrong

Comment: blind me... I am using a UITableViewDiffableDataSource and so the canEdit needed to go into a subclass and blind me didn't see that... So your answer is super valid in my opinion!!! Thanks!!!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to implement `tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath: UITableViewDelegate`'s method and return `UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone` for cells you don't want to show delete control?

Comment: editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath is not called when multiple selection during editing is enabled.